# SyncOrchestrator InvalidComObjectException

Tags: .net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, synchronize

I'm trying to work with Microsofts SyncOrchestrator, but I can't get it worked. Does someone has experience with it and is willing to help me with it?

```
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Files;

public static void SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(FileSyncProvider sourceProvider, FileSyncProvider destinationProvider, Label progress_label)
    {
       try
       {
            SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
            agent.LocalProvider = sourceProvider;
            agent.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
            agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload; // Sync source to destination
            SyncOperationStatistics stats = agent.Synchronize();
       }
       catch { }
    }
```

Calling agent.Synchronize() it gives an

```
InvalidComExceptionError: a com object that has been separated from its underlying rcw cannot be used.
```

Does anybody has an idea what causes this InvalidComExceptionError? Does anyone had this problem before? I couldn't find any reference.

Comment: try changing your projects build target platform (x86/x64) to match the Sync Framework you installed (x86/x64)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I was aware of this issue and checked indeed whether my project and Sync Framework match: they are both x86...